# Occasional slow database queries caused by InnoDB

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb, innodb, myisam

*Update 2017-11-26*

The problem seems to be related to InnoDB. The CI as well as the Wordpress installations are using InnoDB Engines while the rest is working with MyISAM. After I converted all MODx Databases to InnoDB they are having the same issues...Occasional very slow queries causing loading times of > 10 seconds. Here's a screenshot of my monitoring tool from one of my MODx sites (you can see that I switched from MyISAM to InnoDB yesterday and the loading time exploded):

[image: Switched to InnoDB]

Here is my my.cnf:

```
skip_name_resolve               = 1
thread_cache_size               = 4
performance_schema
query_cache_type                = 0
query_cache_limit               = 0
query_cache_size                = 0
join_buffer_size                = 4M
tmp_table_size                  = 250M
max_heap_table_size             = 250M


innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 1
innodb_log_file_size            = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 185M
innodb_io_capacity              = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_log_file_size            = 23M
```

Database Statistics (after converted MODx from MyISAM to InnoDB):

- Data in MyISAM tables: 589K (Tables: 16)
- Data in InnoDB tables: 131M (Tables: 1089)

**Problem**

I am running a CentOS 7 machine with Nginx 1.10.2 + PHP 7.1.10 (php-fpm) + MariaDB 10.1.28. Using this machine I am serving the following applications:

- 4x Laravel 5.x
- 10x MODx Revo 2.5.8
- 1x Wordpress 4.8.3
- 2x CI 3.1.6

While my Laravel and MODx Revo applications are running super fast without any issues, my status monitors, slow logs (PHP-FPM and MariaDB Slowlog) and manual testing verify that from approx. 10 requests to my Wordpress and CI applications 3 reqs. are very slow (slowest around 5-7 seconds) while the other 7 reqs. are quick as expected.

**Wordpress**

*www-slow.log (PHP-FPM)*

```
[13-Nov-2017 09:44:09]  [pool www] pid 24000
script_filename = /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/index.php
[0x00007ff6f7412aa0] mysqli_query() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1942
[0x00007ff6f7412a20] _do_query() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1830
[0x00007ff6f7412940] query() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:2185
[0x00007ff6f74127f0] update() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/option.php:342
[0x00007ff6f74126d0] update_option() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php:1817
[0x00007ff6f7412630] flush_rules() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:298
[0x00007ff6f7412550] apply_filters() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:323
[0x00007ff6f74124e0] do_action() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
[0x00007ff6f74123e0] do_action() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-settings.php:469
[0x00007ff6f7412230] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-config.php:117
[0x00007ff6f74121b0] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-load.php:37
[0x00007ff6f7412110] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php:13
[0x00007ff6f7412080] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress/index.php:17
```

*slow.log (MariaDB)*

```
# User@Host: wordpress[wordpress] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 6810  Schema: wordpress  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 19.189590  Lock_time: 0.000046  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Rows_affected: 1
#
# explain: id   select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    r_rows  filtered    r_filtered  Extra
# explain: 1    SIMPLE  wp_options  range   option_name option_name 766 NULL    1   1.00    100.00  100.00  Using where
#
SET timestamp=1510527877;
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '' WHERE `option_name` = 'rewrite_rules';
```

**CI**

*www-slow.log (PHP-FPM)*

```
[12-Nov-2017 23:08:02]  [pool www] pid 23991
    script_filename = /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/index.php
    [0x00007ff6f74133c0] query() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php:184
    [0x00007ff6f7413350] _execute() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/database/DB_driver.php:791
    [0x00007ff6f74132e0] simple_query() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/database/DB_driver.php:654
    [0x00007ff6f74131b0] query() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php:358
    [0x00007ff6f7413110] _get_lock() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php:151
    [0x00007ff6f7413080] read() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/libraries/Session/Session.php:143
    [0x00007ff6f7413030] session_start() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/libraries/Session/Session.php:143
    [0x00007ff6f7412f60] __construct() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1279
    [0x00007ff6f7412e40] _ci_init_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1172
    [0x00007ff6f7412d20] _ci_load_stock_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1037
    [0x00007ff6f7412c10] _ci_load_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1083
    [0x00007ff6f7412b00] _ci_load_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:173
    [0x00007ff6f7412a00] library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:192
    [0x00007ff6f7412950] libraries() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:153
    [0x00007ff6f7412850] library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1353
    [0x00007ff6f7412790] _ci_autoloader() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:157
    [0x00007ff6f7412740] initialize() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:65
    [0x00007ff6f7412690] initialize() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Controller.php:79
    [0x00007ff6f74125f0] __construct() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Base.php:55
    [0x00007ff6f7412560] __construct() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Base.php:60
```

*slow.log (MariaDB)*

```
# Time: 171112 23:08:05
# User@Host: ci[ci] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 6445  Schema: pm  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 16.833340  Lock_time: 0.000049  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 168
# Rows_affected: 1
#
# explain: id   select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    r_rows  filtered    r_filtered  Extra
# explain: 1    SIMPLE  ci_un_sessions  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    168 168.00  100.00  0.60    Using where
#
use pm;
SET timestamp=1510524485;
UPDATE `ci_un_sessions` SET `timestamp` = 1510524468, `data` = '__ci_last_regenerate|i:1510524343;requested_page|s:41:\"http://example.com/projects/view/19\";user_id|s:1:\"1\";username|s:9:\"admin\";role_id|s:1:\"1\";status|s:1:\"1\";previous_page|s:41:\"http://example.com/projects/view/19\";'
WHERE `id` = '0a75c6tl27pngqnfrh261okdvuotth50';
```

I also tried to switch the database driver in CI from PDO to Mysqli...this didn't change anything. Also I ran all those slow queries in Phpmyadmin, and they perform super fast...so finally in CI I switched session from DB to Session_files_driver causing the slowlog to print:

```
[12-Nov-2017 23:27:00]  [pool www] pid 23991
script_filename = /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/index.php
[0x00007ff6f7413140] flock() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php:178
[0x00007ff6f7413080] read() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/libraries/Session/Session.php:143
[0x00007ff6f7413030] session_start() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/libraries/Session/Session.php:143
[0x00007ff6f7412f60] __construct() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1279
[0x00007ff6f7412e40] _ci_init_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1172
[0x00007ff6f7412d20] _ci_load_stock_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1037
[0x00007ff6f7412c10] _ci_load_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1083
[0x00007ff6f7412b00] _ci_load_library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:173
[0x00007ff6f7412a00] library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:192
[0x00007ff6f7412950] libraries() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:153
[0x00007ff6f7412850] library() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:1353
[0x00007ff6f7412790] _ci_autoloader() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Loader.php:157
[0x00007ff6f7412740] initialize() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php:65
[0x00007ff6f7412690] initialize() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/system/core/Controller.php:79
[0x00007ff6f74125f0] __construct() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Base.php:55
[0x00007ff6f7412560] __construct() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Base.php:60
[0x00007ff6f7412500] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Controller.php:4
[0x00007ff6f74124a0] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /usr/share/nginx/www/ci/application/third_party/MX/Modules.php:123
[0x00007ff6f7412400] autoload() unknown:0
[0x00007ff6f74123a0] spl_autoload_call() unknown:0
```

Profiling of a slow query

```
MariaDB [user]> UPDATE `fx_un_sessions` SET `timestamp` = 1511872955 WHERE `id` = 'hrpsbbvr785cndmmo9n1iqnrek7teqi3';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (8.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000097 |
| checking permissions | 0.000015 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000031 |
| After opening tables | 0.000013 |
| System lock          | 0.000012 |
| Table lock           | 0.000012 |
| init                 | 0.000065 |
| updating             | 0.000088 |
| end                  | 0.000016 |
| query end            | 8.077103 |
| closing tables       | 0.000059 |
| Unlocking tables     | 0.000034 |
| freeing items        | 0.000019 |
| updating status      | 0.000032 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000136 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000035 |
+----------------------+----------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Looks like there is issue with MySQL. It's slow. Could you show MySQL configuration?

Comment: Yes, but I also tried to change session driver of CI to file instead of database and even here I received slow logs in php-fpm. I updated my post to show my server.cnf configuration. The rest is basically default. Do you need more information?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev You were right, the problem is related to MySQL, not in general but to InnoDB Engine. After I converted my MODx Databases from MyISAM to InnoDB they are having the same issues as CI and Wordpress (which are using InnoDB). Any ideas?